# What is the correct way to use Record.ExceptionAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

What is the correct way to use `Record.ExceptionAsync`?

`await Record.ExceptionAsync(async () => await x.GetAsync())`

OR

`await Record.ExceptionAsync(() => x.GetAsync())`

Example:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task ShouldValidateDuplicateEmailOnSave()
{
    var user = new User();
    var predicate = () => It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>();
    var sut = _autoMock.Create<IUserService>();
    var validator = _autoMock.Mock<IUniquenessValidator<User>>();
    validator
        .Setup(m => m.Validate<EmailUniquenessError>(predicate.Invoke()))
        .Throws(new EmailUniquenessError());

    var actual = await Record.ExceptionAsync(() => sut.Save(user)); // I don't use postfix "Async"

    Assert.NotNull(actual);
    Assert.IsType<EmailUniquenessError>(actual);
    validator.Verify(v => v.Validate<EmailUniquenessError>(predicate.Invoke()), Times.Once);
}
```

I don't understand what the difference is and I don't see it in tests.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a big difference. The async/await simply introduces a state machine to unwrap the value inside the `Task<>`.

So, doubling down:

```
await Record.ExceptionAsync(async () => await x.GetAsync())
```

From the unit tests perspective, this is equivalent to:

```
await Record.ExceptionAsync(() => x.GetAsync())
```

The one difference here is the code has to work a little bit harder to unwrap the Task inside the lambda when you double down on async/await. As long as you await outside the lambda, the unit test should be fine.